# Checking if thumbnail exists in PHP

Tags: php, image, opendir

My directory structure looks like that.

```
 ...photo-album1/
 ...photo-album1/thumbnails/
```

Lets say we have `image1.jpg` inside `photo-album1/`. Thumbnail of this file is `tn_image1.jpg`

What I wanna do is to check every file inside `photo-album1/` if they have thumbnail in `photo-album1/thumbnails/`. If they have just continue if not, send file name to another function : `generateThumb()`

How can I do that?

Comment: glob() to get dir listing, foreach() to loop, file_exists() to check

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @j08691 script is very long to post here

Comment: I'd say, just link the thumbnails, then visit the website and scan your webservers error log for 404's of missing thumbnails. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$dir = "/path/to/photo-album1";

// Open directory, and proceed to read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)) {
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
    // Walk through directory, $file by $file
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
      // Make sure we're dealing with jpegs
      if (preg_match('/\.jpg$/i', $file)) {
        // don't bother processing things that already have thumbnails
        if (!file_exists($dir . "thumbnails/tn_" . $file)) {
          // your code to build a thumbnail goes here
        }
      }
    }
    // clean up after ourselves
    closedir($dh);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$dir = '/my_directory_location';
$files = scandir($dir);//or use 
$files =glob($dir);
foreach($files as $ind_file){
if (file_exists($ind_file)) {
    echo "The file $filexists exists";
    } else {
    echo "The file $filexists does not exist";
    }

}
```

Comment: what's that? lol. I know file_exists() function. the problem is I can't figure out how to get files one by one from parent directory and check for thum in thumbnails dir

Comment: use a foreach loop? and post ur code? rofl without it none can give a solution

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to use PHP's `glob` function:

```
$path = '../photo-album1/*.jpg';
$files = glob($path);
foreach ($files as $file) {
   if (file_exists($file)) {
      echo "File $file exists.";
   } else {
      echo "File $file does not exist.";
   }
}
```

Credit to soul above for the basics. I'm just adding glob to it.

EDIT: As hakre points out, glob only returns existing files, so you can speed it up by just checking to see if the filename is in the array. Something like:

```
if (in_array($file, $files)) echo "File exists.";
```

Comment: Hmm, doesn't glob return only existing files? ;)